# Where does Hermione live?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

Harry lives in 4 Privet Drive, Ron lives in The Burrow, and Sirius lives in 12 Grimmauld Place. But where do Hermione and her Muggle parents live?

Comment: I imagine Hermione lives at the library. =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Unclear.

In the books we never get a clear indicator of where she lives, but from the movies she lives in Hampstead, London.

> Now’s your chance to live like Hermione Granger—during summer vacation from Hogwarts, anyway. The house used as Emma Watson’s teenage witch’s family home in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 1 is up for sale for the first time in sixty years, according to the listing. Situated in a cul-de-sac in the northern London suburb of Hampstead, it’s a spacious three-level, six-bedroom home with a classic, verdant back garden; you can just imagine the fictional dentists Mr. and Mrs. Granger raising their super-studious daughter Hermione in the light-filled living room.
> <sub>*- [You Can Now Live in Hermione Granger's House from the Harry Potter Movies
>    - Time](http://time.com/4508563/hermione-harry-potter-house-sale/)*</sub>

So if we are to trust the movies; she lived in Hampstead, but other than that there is no mention of where she lives (in the books).

Comment: Good find! However, the location where a scene is shot is not necessarily where the movie intends it to take place, so I'm not sure this tells us that this is where Hermione lived in the movies.